# Spyder call-tips obscure the current edit line

Tags: spyder

The call-tips make it impossible to see what I'm typing on the bottom line of the console -

[image]

One solution, of course, is to scroll the screen, but this gets annoying after a while, since you eventually reach the bottom of the console screen.
Is there a friendlier solution?
Is this related to the fact that I'm using a high DPI (4k) screen? I have "Enable auto high DPI scaling" ticked.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) We have an option to not show those calltips. Have you tried that already?

Comment: I like the call-tips - I just don't like them in the way. :-)